# How to update the plot of complex roots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy, polynomials

I would like to consecutively plot the (complex) roots of several [Jacobi polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials). The parameters and degree of these polynomials change with a size factor n. By now I have the code to compute the roots and to plot them in the complex plane, but I would like each plot to overwrite the previous one, so as to see whether a pattern of the roots will develop.

The code that I have written by now (using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [sympy](https://www.sympy.org)) produces the plots, but they are all separate ones.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
from sympy import *
import numpy
x = sympy.symbols('x')

def show_roots(n,a,b,c):
    for k in range (1,n+1):
        p = sympy.jacobi(a*k,-(a+b)*k,(b+c)*k,x)
        coeff = sympy.poly(p).coeffs()
        roots = numpy.roots(coeff)
        X = [x.real for x in roots]
        Y = [x.imag for x in roots]
        plt.scatter(X,Y, color='red')
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.5)
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I was a bit too fast in copying the code so it looks a bit clumsy. But thank you.

Comment: What about saving the figures to files on disk and then build some gif out of these if you want an animation for example? Could you please also consider adding a question to your post?

Comment: Can you give reasonable values for n,a,b,c so we can try to recreate and show you how to update the plots.